# Clicking to reload an updated answer removes the closed notification

Tags: bug

When I click to reload an answer that has been updated, the (new) closed notification goes away.

The steps to reproduce my problem:

1. I view a question
2. It gets closed as a duplicate (and then the page updates to show
   this)
3. Someone changes their answer slightly (and I get a reload button
   after some time)
4. I click to reload their answer
5. The closed box goes away

Comment: That is kinda hard to reproduce.

Comment: Yeah, it's kinda unfortunate.